# sysvinit services not starting on boot, upstart services starting

Tags: 14.04, boot, services

I have a problem with my Ubuntu server installation :/ The server runs several services, e.g. postfix, dovecot (as a mailserver), apache2, mysqld, elasticsearch. Normally on startup, these services should start automatically, unhappily they don't do it anymore after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from 12.04.

I have no wide knowledge of ubuntu startup and services, so i don't know what to do. I have checked, if the runlevel is correct after startup (yes it is, N 2), but that's all i did.

What i find out is, that it seems, that only upstart services (which has a config in /etc/init/) starting automatically (e.g. mysqld, dovecot). Services which using sysvinit (/etc/init.d) doesn't start (e.g. postfix, apache2).

I can start the services manually via an ssh (upstart service) connection without any problems, so i don't think, that's a problem of the services itself.

Hope someone can help me :(

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Logfiles:

dmesg: http://pastebin.com/uwrwhVmT

syslog: http://pastebin.com/8fczRUE1

boot.log: empty

kern: pastebin.com/TA9GiG95

EDIT2:

I have read and looked into it a little bit more and it seems, that all services, which can be started via upstart, are starting, while services using sysvinit instead doesn't start anymore.

rc-sysvinit.conf script: pastebin.com/77sMbBy0

EDIT3:

For a test i moved apache2 to rcS, too, and it starts automatically. I did this, because i saw the following line in `rc-sysinit.conf`:

```
[ -n "${FROM_SINGLE_USER_MODE}" ] || /etc/init.d/rcS
```

I checked the entiere file against 14.04 source, but can't find any difference. It's frustraiting, i can't be a solution to move all required services to rcS?! :)

EDIT4:

Now i had a tip from rbasak in #ubuntu-server irc, and followed the steps of the startup.

`/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` successfully calls (tracked with logger) `/etc/init.d/rcS` which executes `/etc/init.d/rc S` (the run level `S` i have tracked with logger). Aftter this, `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` executes `telinit "${DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL}"` (DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL is 2, tracked with logger), but `/etc/init.d/rc` isn't executed after this (it should run and the logger statement should log the runlevel `2`). Any suggestions?

Comment: You should search errors in dmesg, syslog, boot.log and kern.log in /var/log folder, if you want post this file on http://pastebin.com/ and update your question with link.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment. I added the log files to pastebin and edited my question. I can't find anything :/

Comment: Did you modify /etc/rsyslog.conf? There are errors about `Bad file descriptor` If not, could be related to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1366829). Could you reboot your server and post /var/log/syslog immediately after boot ends?

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I forgot to say: The logs are taken directly after a reboot (i cleaned the existing logs after taking a backup and copied the complete logs to the pastebin). Should i take  new logs? And rsyslog.conf i haven't changed. Hope that helps you to help me, if you need more information, please say :)

Comment: Okey, log files are strange, may be due to problem in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, could you post it?

Comment: The only change i made was deactivating kernel logging (was generating errors and this because kernel logging is not working on virtual hosts, i have read). rsyslog.conf: http://pastebin.com/wm1E2VsM and the default logging conf: http://pastebin.com/hRZTnLUf

Comment: So one error in rsyslog.conf is due to `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on`. This directive need `imklog` module that is commented. You should comment `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` too.

Comment: Could you post ownership and permission of /dev/xconsole folder?

Comment: There is no directory /dev/xconsole, just /dev/console with `crw` and owner `root`. The `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` i have commented, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at last line in `50-default.conf`, may be you should comment it because /dev/xconsole doesn't exist. In syslog you can see the error `Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory`

Comment: Could you reboot and post log file after those corrections? I hope we found more logs.

Comment: Made the corrections, here the logs: dmesg: empty; syslog: http://pastebin.com/qe0NKfiM boot.log: empty; kern.log: empty; The services doesn't start automatically, too :( What i saw now is, that rc.local scripts are not executed, too. I hope we find a solution, i have no muse to reinstall the server :/ Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you mean that the only services that do not start are those performed by rc.local? If rc.local doesn't run, probably there is an error, so, could you post rc.local?

Comment: No, in rc.local i have only `/etc/iptables.local` (and `exit 0` as the last line) to load a bunch of iptables rules at startup (which doesn't load automatically now, so i must run `/etc/iptables.local` manually, which will work without any error/problem). There are othe services (like i said), that doesn't start on boot, too, including e.g. apache2, postfix, elasticsearch but excluding mysqld and dovecot (which starts automatically, like you see in the logs).

Comment: I have read and looked into it a little bit more and it seems, that all services, which can be started via upstart, are starting, while services using sysvinit instead doesn't start anymore. Now i have to find out, why it is so, comments/solutions welcome! (question updated)

Comment: about apache2 I guess that new version is 2.4. If you had 2.0 or 2.2 before upgrading Ubuntu, you should update apache configuration file. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) is a useful link.

Comment: But this doesn't solves the problem for other services :/ And init.d scripts should (iirc) work in 14.04, too, so the problem will still exist.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to solve the problem with my suggestion on apache2 :) However it seems that your server starts in recovery mode. Try `telinit 2` and than reboot, it should change your runlevel.

Comment: doesn't help. And after restart the runlevel is N 2 (this should be correct?)

Comment: It is strange, because if boot enter in S mode, at the end it should change to runlevel 2 for the next reboot. So runlevel 2 is right, the problem is: why variable FROM_SINGLE_USER_MODE is set to y or why rc-sysvinit.conf is run with -s option or does /etc/inittab exist and if yes what is the content?

Comment: The runlevel S is the standard before 2, isn't it? /etc/inittab is empty (but exist). What i see now is, that command reboot seems to only shutdown services started with upstart, not services started manually (using service sername start), so the system doesn't reboot (before i used the reboot option in the vServers console, which is working well). Maybe this info is important. I see, that something went very wrong here. If we can't find a solution until weekend, i will go the "new installation" way :/ Hope we can avoid this.

Comment: No, runlevel S is recovery mode and usually it can be entered from GRUB. Did you check if /etc/rcN.d folders contain symbolic links to /etc/init.d scripts as you expect?

Comment: Jap, that i have checked. For elasticsearch i have created the symlinks new already, but no luck :( Ok, thx for clarify runlevel S :) But what are the reasons for entering it for a vServer? And why rl 2 is set correctly (and upstart services run normaly?)

Comment: I'm not sure, but, could you remove /etc/inittab? It is empty, so it shouldn't modify DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL variable, but usually this file is not present unless you want to change the default value of runlevel at bootstrap. Yes, you are right, it is strange this runlevel behavior.

Comment: Upstart emit `runlevel` event at `shutdown` or `reboot` so upstart jobs that hook this event on `stop on` stanza, will stop. One of this jobs is `/etc/init/rc.conf` that runs `/etc/init.d/rc` with 0 (shutdown) or 6 (reboot). This script should run /etc/rc0.d or /etc/rc6.d script. I guess that runlevel event is correctly emitted so upstart jobs stop, while something goes wrong in `/etc/init.d/rc` script and `sendsigs` is not executed. This script is the one that kills the remaining processes not already stopped.

Comment: I have renamed /etc/inittab to inittab.old and restarted, same result :(

Comment: Could you post your `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`? I guess problem is in this file. Could you try to reboot after `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf debug` command? This will trace init event and we'll see runlevel event.

Comment: Here the rc-sysinit.conf http://pastebin.com/d01ghEyQ
/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf debug results in a permission denied (no x flag).

Comment: Big thanks for your help, but i have now decided to reinstall the server. It was a lot of work to get all services up and working again without to restore too many configuration, but now it's working (and a restart/boot works very well).

Comment: I'm sorry not being able to help you.

Comment: Me too :( The worst thing is, to not know what went wrong :/ Nevertheless, thanks for your try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries to fix the problem or find out, what the problem is, i have now reinstalled with the actual Ubuntu 14.04 image and all is working now. Unhappily i can't say, what the problem was :(